# mysql query select 4 tables having timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

hello friends i have a problem in getting data from 4 tables which are having timestamps but 
the thing is i have 2 tables in which timestamp is in UNIX format for eg "1326503655" and 2 tables in which the timestamp is "2012-01-02 01:20:58" format 
how to arrange the tables according to the timestamp and according to the user id

here are my tables

1- message

```
 msg_id |message |uid_fk |  ip |created |uploads |f_id |type_id
```

here uid_fk is user id and created is timestamp in UNIX

2- comments

```
 com_id |comment |msg_id_fk |uid_fk|ip |created |cfid |type_id
```

here uid_fk is user id and created is timestamp in UNIX

3 -   gallery

```
       picId| albumId |userId |photo| timestamp
```

here the timestamp is in "2012-01-02 01:20:58" format .

4 -  adore

```
       id|  uid |friend_id |timestamp
```

here the timestamp is also in "2012-01-02 01:20:58" format

m not able to arrange them by timestamp  can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not understanding, what you are trying to achieve, but you can convert a UNIX timestamp to a `DATETIME` using `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view that holds all dates in DATETIME format.

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT msg_id, message, uid_fk, ip, FROM_UNIXTIME(created) date, uploads, f_id, type_id, message FROM messages
UNION
SELECT * FROM ...
```

Even though, you would probably be better off refactorizing your database and storing all dates in the same format.

Comment: thanks for the idea but how to arrange them according to the timestamp as in 2 tables the name of the row is created for storing timestamp and in other 2 it is timestamp for storing the timestamp . hope u get me what i want to say

Comment: After you have crated your view, you can just do `SELECT * FROM v ORDER BY date;`

Comment: thanks for helping when i use this query CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT msg_id, message, uid_fk, ip, FROM_UNIXTIME(created), uploads, f_id, type_id, message FROM messages
UNION
SELECT * FROM  adore
ORDER BY date  i get this error "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: Yes, since the tables have a different number of rows. What kind of output exactly do you expect? Please include a sample in your question.

Comment: the output i want is that m making a user activity , in which he comments , messages , adore , gallery upload , all comes in timestamp what even acitvity he has done is arranged by timestamp .

Comment: I asked for a code sample, since I was uncertain whether you have thought it through or not, because you seemed confused by the error message you posted. The 4 tables don't have the same field names, not even the same amount of column. When you want all of this in one table, you had to understand that you'd get some rather odd output.